# Invalid object name 'CHANGETABLE'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, change-tracking, invalid-object-name

I just enabled change tracking by turning on *ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION*, executing this query to turn on change tracking for the database

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS,AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
```

and by finally enabling it on the table

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF)
```

Now when I call

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES, 0)
```

I get this error message:

> Invalid object name 'CHANGETABLE'.

The database version is SQL Server 2012. How can `CHANGETABLE` be invalid and how can I make it work? I assumed it would work out of the box because it's a system function. It's even highlighted in SQL Server Management Studio. I modified a little bit of data between turning on change tracking and calling `CHANGETABLE()`.

Comment: Typically you should prefix functions with their schema... have you tried sys.changetable() or dbo.changetable()?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) ? `CHANGETABLE (CHANGES)` requires a table name, eg `select * FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES Employees, @last_sync_version) AS C`

Comment: Prefixing changetable with dbo or sys, both return invalid object name

Comment: @pmbAustin `CHANGETABLE` is a T-SQL function, not a UDF

Comment: @Cambesa the query you wrote is wrong. You forgot the table name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much, adding the table name to the function makes it work. I used an example that did not include the table name in the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [correct syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#changetablechanges) is

```
SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES MyTableName,@last_version) as SomeAlias
```

This is shown in the [documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) :

```
DECLARE @last_sync_version bigint;  
SET @last_sync_version = <value obtained from query>;  

SELECT [Emp ID], SSN,  
    SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,  
    SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT   
FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES Employees, @last_sync_version) AS C;
```

Forgetting the table name results in `Invalid object name 'CHANGETABLE'`

Forgetting the table alias results in `A table returned by the CHANGETABLE function must be aliased.`